# Access copies changes across all tabs

Tags: ms-access

On an Access 2016 form, I have a tab control.
In one tab, I put text boxes stuff in. But when I make a new tab, the layout is a duplicate of the first tab, and whenever I make a change, it is mirrored to the first tab too. 
For example, if I add a text box to the second tab, it appears on the first tab as well, and if I add one on the first, it appears on the second. Is there a property to change? Sorry but I can't find one. 
Thank you,
-Lewis

Comment: Sounds like you're not working inside the tab of the tab control, but just beneath it. Make sure you're working inside the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sounds like you're not working inside the tab of the tab control, but
>   just beneath it. Make sure you're working inside the tab. – Erik von
>   Asmuth 8 mins ago

Thank you Erik, the textboxes were over the tab control instead of inside it. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: Good. Flagging question as off-topic because of simple error.